# How to tag previous commits in git and github?

Tags: git, git-tag

How do I tag all commits with a new tag?

I know how to tag a single commit but how can I do it on bulk, and the push the tags up to GitHub?

Comment: What do you mean by tagging *all* commits!?

Comment: @johannes Ok - so in my master branch I have around 50 commits. I have only recently been introduced to tagging in git/github. So I want to go back to the first commit and apply tag v1 so all 50 commits are tagged as v1 as I am about to begin v2. Also want those tags to be pushed up to github.com

i will then make a v1 release in github too. jQuery use the tagging system.

Comment: thats not how you use tags.... use tags to mark releases, ie. tag the final commit of your v1 work as v1, and then start v2.

Comment: ok. so just place a tag on commit 50 (last commit of the version)? How do I push this up to github?

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.0.2/.editorconfig

Comment: Do you want to continue developing on the v1 series (bug fixing or such?) then make it a branch (`git branch v1` or such) and continue on master, if not you can tag your last v1 or first v2 commit to find it again, aside from that one typically tags as part of a release process

Comment: @johannes I was thinking of making a v1, v2 branch etc, then tagging v1.2, v1.3 etc

using 0.0.0.0 format for releases. any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: yes, that sounds correct.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot tag all commits with one tag. A tag can point to only one commit, so even if you run through all your history and tag them you'll face to problems:

1. You'll need to use `-f` option to tag, because once you place a tag, a tag with the same name can only be forced
2. After your script end, the tag will point to the last commit.

But, as I mentioned, it is possible. You can iterate through output of `git log` and place tags (with different names), or you can use libraries ([JGit](http://www.jgit.org/), for example). After tags are placed, do `git push github --tags`.

P.S. I think you are trying to do something bad. Tell us why do you need it?